# Struts : is there a way to test the current module?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

In a JSP, I want part of the content to be module dependent. How do I test the current module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ModuleUtils.getInstance().getModuleConfig(request, application).getPrefix()
```

does just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in **ModuleUtils** called [getModuleName](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/api/org/apache/struts/util/ModuleUtils.html#getModuleName%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletContext%29). You can use it in a scriptlet or create a separate tag for that.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work.

I have two modules sharing tiles (JSPs). If I test the module using

 <%request.setAttribute("currentModuleName", ModuleUtils.getInstance().getModuleName(request, pageContext.getServletContext()));%>

in a jsp stored in /pages/bla/page.jsp, the module is identified as "" (the test is done on the request.getServletPath() by ModuleUtils, so it doesn't get me the current running module.